# Manipulate a collection to produce a condensed version

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm currently stumped on a small piece of functionality that I can't seem to figure out.

Firstly I have a `Stock` class that looks as follows:

```
public class Stock
{
    public int Id;
    public int LocationId;
    public int Quantity;
}
```

`Stock` logs are returned from the database which are produced from another piece of functionality. The log is represented as a `List<Stock>` collection - however I need to add the `Quantity` property of each object of the same `ID` and `LocationID` combination, for example:

> Original Data Set:
>
> ID: 1    Location: 1    Quantity: 20
>
> ID: 1    Location: 2    Quantity: 30
>
> ID: 1    Location: 1    Quantity: 30
>
> ID: 2    Location: 2    Quantity: 20
>
> ID: 1    Location: 2    Quantity: 30
>
> ID: 1    Location: 1    Quantity: 100

Should return:

> Condensed Data Set:
>
> ID: 1    Location: 1    Quantity: 150
>
> ID: 1    Location: 2    Quantity: 60
>
> ID: 2    Location: 2    Quantity: 20

To reiterate: The data set is dynamically returned from a database, there is no guarantee that there will be every `ID` & `LocationID` combination and I need the resultant data set to be unique on a compound key of `ID` and `LocationID`.

Not sure about the most effective way of going about this and it's holding back my progress with the project, any advice or approaches would be much appreciated. I'm kind of thinking this is a knowledge gap really but I've not been able to find anything appropriate / that fits my requirements (it's quite an odd requirement I guess).

Many thanks,

Andy

Comment: Is there any reason you're not performing the aggregates in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to do this on the database but you can also use GroupBy to achieve the exact same effect:

```
public class Stock
{
    public int Id;
    public int LocationId;
    public int Quantity;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<Stock>()
        {
            new Stock(){ Id = 1, LocationId = 1, Quantity = 20},
            new Stock(){ Id = 1, LocationId = 2, Quantity = 30},
            new Stock(){ Id = 1, LocationId = 1, Quantity = 30},
            new Stock(){ Id = 2, LocationId = 2, Quantity = 20},
            new Stock(){ Id = 1, LocationId = 2, Quantity = 30},
            new Stock(){ Id = 1, LocationId = 1, Quantity = 100},

        };

    var grouped = list.GroupBy(c => new {Id = c.Id, LocationId = c.LocationId})
            .Select(g => new 
                 { 
                      Id = g.Key.Id, 
                      LocationId = g.Key.LocationId, 
                      Quantity = g.Sum(a => a.Quantity) 
                  });
    foreach(var group in grouped.OrderBy(c => c.Id))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Id:{0} - LocationId:{1} - Quantity:{2}", group.Id, 
                 group.LocationId, group.Quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, considering you mentioned making the aggregation at the database (which I ended up doing) and still gave a C# answer this is just what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `GroupBy` to do this:

```
var grouped = (from s in stocks
                group s by new { s.Id, s.LocationId }
                    into grp
                    select new Stock()
                    {
                        Id = grp.Key.Id,
                        LocationId = grp.Key.LocationId,
                        Quantity = grp.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I will prefer to use SQL query something like this :

```
select id, location, sum(quantity) quant from stocktable group by id, location
```

This helps in getting the computation done at the db itself helping you in terms of performance. As the DB server will anyway read and give all the data to app layer, there is no performance penalty and you gain in terms of simplicity.

Comment: Seeing as I posted this as a C# question and there were useful C# answers that have helped me I felt obliged to mark one of those as the answer, however I did implement the suggestion you made and it was a very useful, simplistic solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.GroupBy` to perform the grouping and `Enumerable.Aggregate` (or, in this case the specialised `Sum`) to perform the aggregation.

Something along the lines of:

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int, int>> result =
    stocks.GroupBy(stock => new { id = stock.Id, locationId = stock.LocationId},
                   (key, s) => new { key.id, key.locationId, total = s.Sum(ss => ss.Quantity) });

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.id);
    Console.WriteLine(result.locationId);
    Console.WriteLine(result.total);
}
```